# How to rename columns from spark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a small dataframe in sparksession and I want to change the column names

```
my_sess.sql('SELECT * from data LIMIT 10').show()

+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+---+
|5.1|3.5|1.4|0.2|
|4.9|3.0|1.4|0.2|
|4.7|3.2|1.3|0.2|
|4.6|3.1|1.5|0.2|
|5.0|3.6|1.4|0.2|
|5.4|3.9|1.7|0.4|
|4.6|3.4|1.4|0.3|
|5.0|3.4|1.5|0.2|
|4.4|2.9|1.4|0.2|
|4.9|3.1|1.5|0.1|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Here all the column names are numeric value, and I want to change them to a, b, c, d? How can I do it?

```
my_sess.sql('DESCRIBE data').show()

+--------+---------+-------+
|col_name|data_type|comment|
+--------+---------+-------+
|       0|   double|   null|
|       1|   double|   null|
|       2|   double|   null|
|       3|   double|   null|
+--------+---------+-------+
```

I tried using ALTER command but it didn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename columns like this:

```
new_columns = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

for old, new in zip(data.columns, new_columns):
    data = data.withColumnRenamed(old, new)
```

Comment: thank you... Can I know from where I learn all these methods/attributes?

Comment: @user_12 This is a good starting point [Pyspark API documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/index.html)